Past Simple or Past Perfect? "We [finish] eating our lunch and we were taking the plates out to the kitchen"
Here's my question: 
We ___ eating our lunch and we were taking the plates out to the kitchen.
 A finished
 B were finishing
 C ’ve finished
 D ’d finished
It seems that this should be Past Simple (finished), since the two actions were consequential and Past Perfect (to me anyway) seems unnecessary. Please explain what I am missing, because the Answer Key claims it should be  'd finished, as if it's necessary to show that one came before the other. I thought it's unnecessary!
Also there's ChatGPT (which I'd like to double check as well) that says mixing Past Simple and Past Continuous in this way is grammatically accurate yet "can feel slightly awkward". Knowledgeable folks, please clarify! Many thanks.

Past perfect or Simple past.
OP's sentence is

We ___ eating our lunch and we were taking the plates out to the kitchen.
A finished.
B were finishing.
C ’ve finished.
D ’d finished.

The second "we" in the sentence is redundant.
When to use the Past perfect tense..
Two actions that happened in the past. One action happened before the other. The older action is expressed in the past perfect.

By the time they reached the station, the train had already left.
OR.
When they reached the station, the train had already left..

Using the past perfect is not always necessary; for example, we can modify the above sentence to Simple Past by adding "before"..
The train left the station before they reached.

Ref. Collins dictionary
You use 'and' to link two statements about events when one of the events follows the other.
I waved goodbye and went down the stone harbour steps..
I pulled the door closed and did up my boots on the landing..

Both OP and ChatGPT are correct - the question has two correct answers, both conveying the same meaning (and in OP's sentence means after we finished eating lunch). Native speakers prefer to avoid Past Perfect tense whenever they can. However if you are answering for a written test, choose 'D', as your answer.
We finished eating our lunch and were taking the plates out to the kitchen.
We'd finished eating our lunch and were taking the plates out to the kitchen.

I don't like this answer. The use of imperfect "were taking" establishes a reference point in the past as during the taking out. This puts "finished" as being in the past with respect to the reference, which is itself in the past, which means we need the Past Perfect. If we use simple past "finished" then the second part should be also simple past.

@DJClayworth : I had mentioned that D is the correct answer. OP had asked if using Simple Past tense is correct. Other respondents have also agreed to it.
Do you have proper reference why it is incorrect? The rule is that a sentence in Past perfect tense can be rewritten in Simple Past tense by using 'before', 'after', 'and' etc.
Cambridge dictionary example: (used to join two parts of a sentence, one part happening after or because of the other part) after that; then: I met Jonathan, and we went out for a cup of coffee. dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/and

Context, context, context!
I assume this is an exercise from a test or study paper. It's not just about what is right or wrong, it's about what you want to say.

We finished eating our lunch and we were taking the plates out to the kitchen.

The use of the simple past here points to a particular time, the time at which the meal ended. (We finished lunch at 1.30 pm.)

We had finished eating our lunch and we were taking the plates out to the kitchen.

The use of the past perfect here points to the action as a whole, and tells us that the action is complete. Lunch is over, but the dish washing is not. The past perfect helps with that contrast because it puts the two actions in the proper order of time.

We were finishing eating our lunch and we were taking the plates out to the kitchen.

Even this sentence can be correct given the right context. For several years I was part of a community church ministry that would start with a shared meal for 50 people then go on to other activities. Every week it was true that some people were finishing their meals while other people were taking dishes out to the kitchen!

Agreed 100%, but as the exercise requires one choice to be made, D is the most natural. It pinpoints the action at the moment when the protagonists had finished eating and were in the process of clearing the table.

The issue is with the context indeed, because it's kind of a standalone sentence - an MCQ out of a test paper, which probably means (as well as what your response seems to indicate) that both past simple and past perfect are possible, depending on what we would want to communicate. Thanks Peter!

Thanks Kate! So then, past simple in this case doesn't sufficiently illustrate that one action was completed, and the next one was in the process? Past Perfect is the choice then. Would really appreciate a bit of explanation as to why exactly it's not sufficient though ...

I said that past perfect was the most natural. "We finished eating our lunch" could mean "We ate the last few mouthfuls". If they were in the act of taking the plates away, they must have already finished.
